# jQuery's ajax code to load new pages, but I want to get only the html of a div

Tags: jquery, ajax

**HTML Code :**

```
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

**Script:**

```
$.ajax({
  url:href,
  type:'GET',
  success: function(data){
    $('#content').html(data);
  }
});
```

I want to get only the `HTML of $('div#content') on another page`. How to do it?

Comment: You can use `localStorage` to store the `HTML` content of a div.

Comment: I did not got you

Comment: You want to get the `HTML` content of a div into another page `div`, right??

Comment: yes  i want to get the HTML content of a div into another page div,

Comment: Hi @pardeep, The ajax call is going out as cross domain or it's load from the same domain?
If is on the same domain you can do:
$( "#content" ).load( "ajax/test.html #content" );

Comment: @Shiladitya Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

At a single point of time, single page will rendering into the browser. So, you can't find the previous page `HTML` content using `JavaScript`/ `jQuery` into another page.

For that you need to use `localStorage`.

**Page 1** `HTML`

```
<div id="contentToCopy">
  <div>
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

**Page 1** `JavaScript/jQuery`

```
localStorage.setItem('copiedContent', $('#contentToCopy').html());
```

**Page 2** `HTML`

```
<div id="contentToPaste"></div>
```

**Page 2** `JavaScript/jQuery`

```
$('#contentToPaste').html(localStorage.getItem('copiedContent');
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @pardeep Welcome buddy :) Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use jQuery to wrap the data and extract the div content.
Something like this (I have not tested it)

```
$('#content').html($(data).find('div#content'));
```

Comment: Sorry bro it is not Working for me